# So this is my program, but i could not figure out is that how can i redirect just or only all the numbers with :40036 into new data file?

Tags: java

So Below is some of the stuff from the tcpprobe.dat file

```
100.006836647 10.10.1.2:40036 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0xf2037edc 0xf202ebcc 26 19 254848 152 29312
100.031193635 10.10.1.2:40036 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0xf2038a2c 0xf202f71c 26 19 254848 151 29312
100.140239621 10.10.1.2:40037 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x20241c31 0x2023d851 13 11 186880 157 29312
100.152498003 10.10.1.2:40037 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x20242781 0x2023ddf9 14 11 186880 156 29312
100.164485194 10.10.1.2:40037 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x202432d1 0x2023e3a1 14 11 186880 155 29312
100.176630211 10.10.1.2:40037 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x202432d1 0x2023e949 14 11 186880 154 29312
100.188673797 10.10.1.2:40035 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x4fda1ee1 0x4fd9cfb1 15 13 336000 157 29312
100.200744133 10.10.1.2:40035 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x4fda2a31 0x4fd9d559 15 13 336000 156 29312
100.212896515 10.10.1.2:40035 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x4fda2a31 0x4fd9db01 15 13 336000 156 29312
100.225069255 10.10.1.2:40035 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0x4fda3581 0x4fd9e0a9 15 13 336000 155 29312
```

```
public class Process_TCPProbe_TP{ 


    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("tcpprobe.dat"));
            scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
               System.out.print(scanner.next()+",");
            }//end of while  
        scanner.close();
        }//end of try  

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }//end of catch
```

Answer (score 1):

A general approach here would be to first read the file line by line.  Then, split each line on whitespace to isolate each "number" or term.  Finally, print all numbers containing `:40036`:

```
try {
    File f = new File("tcpprobe.dat");
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    String line = "";
    StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String part : parts) {
            if (part.contains(":40036")) {
                if (numbers.length() > 0) numbers.append(",");
                numbers.append(part);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(numbers);
```

**Edit:**

If you instead want to capture each entire matching line/statement, then use this `while` loop:

```
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
    for (String part : parts) {
        if (part.contains(":40036")) {
            if (numbers.length() > 0) numbers.append(",");
            numbers.append(line);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As just a small appendage, you can also use `part.contains(":40036")` in this case instead of `matches`

Comment: @Nexevis Good suggestion.  Too much regex on my brain, which explains why I have no friends anymore `:-P`.

Comment: So when I tried doing it like that it is displaying, 10.10.1.2:40036 and it is running it infinitely, and it is not pritnting it whole statement like "100.006836647 10.10.1.2:40036 10.10.2.2:5001 32 0xf2037edc 0xf202ebcc 26 19 254848 152 29312"

Comment: I gave you a fix if you want to record the entire matching line/statement.  As for "running infinitely," that shouldn't be happening.  Maybe you have a really large text file, so it appears to be running forever.

Comment: Yes, it is a big file containing least 5000 lines with each of them containing three different port numbers containing either 40036, 40035, 40037 where I am trying to display just those lines containing with 40036.

Comment: I can't offer any additional help over the answer I have already given.  It should finish iterating the file at some point.  You may add print statements to ensure that in fact it does match the correct lines.

Comment: Yes it does stop iterating just had to move the print statement